# How to list all notes in an Evernote business notebook

Tags: ruby, evernote

Using https://github.com/evernote/evernote-oauth-ruby, how can I list all notes in a business notebook?

I'm able to get all business notebooks with

```
business_note_store.listNotebooks
```

but, listing all notes where `business_notebook_id` comes from in the above statement, using

```
business_note_store.findNotesMetadata(
  @client.access_token.token,
  filter(business_notebook_id), 0, 200, specs
).notes
```

results in an exception when I use:

```
def filter(notebook_id)
  filter = Evernote::EDAM::NoteStore::NoteFilter.new
  filter.order = Evernote::EDAM::Type::NoteSortOrder::UPDATED
  filter.notebookGuid = notebook_id

  filter
end

def spec
  spec = Evernote::EDAM::NoteStore::NotesMetadataResultSpec.new
  spec.includeTitle = true
  spec.includeUpdated = true

  spec
end
```

Comment: Please take the time to use proper grammar, including spelling and capitalization. Stack Overflow is a reference book in the making, and proper grammar is important. Your effort also affects the willingness of those who will try to help you. Please read "[ask]" including the links at the bottom, which discuss this.

Answer (score 0):

it works, when I removed the token

```
business_note_store.findNotesMetadata(
  filter(business_notebook_id), 0, 200, specs
).notes
```

works fine. now i just wanna know why :)

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment? If it's a comment, don't use answers for that purpose.